# Safe initialisation of null reference

Tags: java, thread-safety, java-memory-model, safe-publication

I'm wondering what publication guarantees exist for a non-final field initialised to null, if any.

Consider the following snippet:

```
public class MyClass {

    private final CopyOnWriteArrayList<Inner> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    //called by thread 1
    public void init() {
        // initialise Inner instance
        list.add(new Inner());
    }

    //called by thread 2
    public void doSomething() {
        for (Inner i : list) {
            // access non-final field
            Object ref = i.ref;
            // do something
            // ...
            // ...

            // potentially set i.ref
        }
    }

    private static class Inner {
        // initialised by thread 1
        Object ref = null;
    }
}
```

Assuming `doSomething()` is always called by thread 2, is this safe? What guarantees are made about what thread 2 will see the first time it's accessed? Is there any possibility thread 2 would see something that's non-null?

Where in the JMM are the semantics around this situation described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JVM` will guarantee that you don't see *out of thin air values*, so anything other than `null` *it not possible*, in case that `List` is not empty (in this example, of course). If there would have been a different thread involved (let's say `Thread3`) that would alter your list (add elements to it), `Thread2` could see those updates. Just note that individual methods of `CopyOnWriteArrayList` are thread safe; your method `doSomething` *is not*.

See the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.8) for the specifics or the excellent (and rather complicated, may be just to me) [Aleksey article](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/jmm-pragmatics/#_part_iv_out_of_thin_air).

Comment: Thanks. On the point: "JVM will guarantee that you don't see out of thin air values, so anything other than null it not possible" - is this guaranteed anywhere in JMM?

Comment: @user2248785 what you are looking for is the `JLS` as the official language spec, not the `JMM` - which is *for compiler writers* (and neither of us is such). This term `out of thin air` is mentioned in the `JLS` *once only*; it's a term I first read about in a book by Brian Goetz - I think it is derived from multiple other places, like `default` values and the like

Comment: Thanks, I believe the OoTA guarantee is the one I was looking for. This is described in [JLS-17.4.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.8). Will accept your answer if you are happy to add the reference.

Comment: @user2248785 which part exactly do you have in mind about that JLS btw? I am reading it now...

Comment: I think the section I referenced above covers it. (i.e. [JLS-17.4.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.8)) There's also an example "Example 17.4.8-1. Happens-before Consistency Is Not Sufficient" which illustrates the concept of OoTA consistency. I also found this [separate document](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/jmm-pragmatics/#_part_iv_out_of_thin_air) a good explanation - it references the same JLS section.

Comment: @user2248785 I added the references for completeness, but truth being said I probably need to re-read them to fully understand...

Answer (score 0):

Talking about safe publication makes sense only when you are initialising a field with a meaningful object that *has the state*. Then, improper publication may lead to observing *a partially constructed object*.

In this case, `null` *doesn't convey any state*. It can be considered *an immutable object*. Immutable objects don't have publication problems.

> What guarantees are made about what thread 2 will see the first time it's accessed?

Thread 2 will see `null` when referring to `i.ref`.
Note that the list may be empty because Thread 1 may not have added an `Inner` to it yet.

> Is there any possibility thread 2 would see something that's non-null?

No.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This was my suspicion. Are you able to reference this back to the JMM specification? I couldn't see anything specifically about this situation...